# how do you find matrix representations for central simple division algebras?

Tags: number-theory, algebras

Suppose that $D$ is a central simple division algebra over a field $K$ and that it splits over $K_{v}$ for some valuation $v$ on $K$. Is there some kind of technique for finding a faithful matrix representation of $D$ over $K_{v}$?